# find fixed vectors $(V = [0, 0, 1])$ new coordinates in new coordinate system

Tags: linear-algebra, 3d

For a robotic camera I'm using, in its default position its Euler angles (roll, pitch, yaw) are 0. In that case, when I am trying to detect planes I look for planes with the normal vector $v = [0, 0, 1]$

However, lets say the camera has moved and now has some given roll, pitch and yaw.

The world is still the same and so I need to find the same planes, what is the equivalent normal vector I should look for in this new position?

Thanks

Comment: Is this a single link system?

Comment: Essentially, after the move I know the new roll pitch and yaw of the camera and that's all. And so I want to know the vector coordinates taking this new orientation of the camera as the origin

Comment: Alright, so essentially you would like to know what $(0,0,1)$ corresponds to w.r.t new axes

Answer (score 1):

You could write it as the product of three rotations

$$R = R_r R_pR_y$$

$$R = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\0 &\cos \alpha & \sin \alpha \\ 0 & -\sin\alpha & \cos\alpha\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}\cos \beta & 0 & \sin \beta \\0 &1 & 0 \\ -\sin\beta & 0 & \cos\beta\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}\cos \gamma & \sin \gamma & 0 \\-\sin \gamma &\cos \gamma & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

So this would be your rotation matrix to reach from your initial position to your final position if $\alpha, \beta , \gamma$ are roll, pitch and yaw

Can you use this to see what happens to $(0,0,1)$

Comment: Thought this was to transform a point, not a vector?

Comment: You can consider the transformation of the vector as the transformation of the difference of the point and origin. From the linearity of the transformation, and the fact that origin is invariant - you can find the vector transformation from the point transformation

Comment: I see that makes sense, what do you mean by "linearity of the transformation" though?

Comment: $T(a-b) = T(a) - T(b)$